# Installing a ruby app as a Linux service

Tags: linux, service, ruby-on-rails

There's a very highly rated application for defect management called Redmine.  It's written in Ruby.  I was able to get it working following their [instructions](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineInstall).  However, I would like to run the application as a service that starts automatically every time the server reboots.  How do you go about adding a Ruby website as a Linux service?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a recent version of Ubuntu, you'll want to write [an Upstart script](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) - as well as that introduction, /etc/init is full of examples.

If you're on anything else, you'll want to create an init script - the [redmine wiki](http://wiki.contribs.org/Redmine#Starting_and_stopping_the_Redmine_server) has an example, specifically tailored for redmine.

Comment: That's a great link.  I think that will work.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "Ruby website"; a *Rails* site needs an application server process running to serve requests for the app, this is typically one of mongrel, thin, or unicorn (if you're using webrick, you're on a loser already).

Your options are, broadly:

1. Write an init script for it, invoke that init script on boot as per the procedure for your particular distribution
2. Use an @reboot rule in cron (uuuuugly)
3. Use something like daemontools to manage the server process

I do (3), because it is awesome.  I expect a lot of people to recommend monit in place of daemontools; I've done that, and I hated every second of it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this:

http://rubyworks.rubyforge.org/

Once having your system set up properly to run as a real server for Ruby stuff, you can then insert your Redmine application into it's environment.

Comment: The cluelessness contained in that one page scares the wallop out of me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have apache or some other web server already running, you don't need to run Redmine as a separate service - just have it run under your web server. For Apache Just follow the instructions for installing Passenger here:

http://www.modrails.com/install.html

And then add an entry in Apache that points to the path to that site, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mycook.com
    DocumentRoot /webapps/mycook/public
    <Directory /webapps/mycook/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application